# Why high order function is not popular in numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

For example, when you do `x * y + z`
with high order function, it can be expressed as : `on3(x,y,add,lambda (x,y,z): x * y + z)` which in theory could save lots of computations.
My question is why such patterns are rare in numpy

Comment: Is this really about `numpy` or python?  `numpy` provides object classes (mainly `ndarray`) and functions.  Python sets the syntax.  Python is OOP, but doesn't force you to write custom classes.  Functions are first class objects, and can be passed as argumeents.  Under the covers there's a lot function passing and delegation methods.

Comment: Explain how your alternative expression is supposed to save computations.  If it helps describe both the scalar and the array cases.

Comment: Your question needs more context.  Are you asking about end users like us?  Or why python doesn't provide more tools for this (the wiki article has a python example). Or why `numpy` doesn't more compiled building blocks like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you say `x * y + z` with NumPy arrays, `x * y` will allocate a temporary array and then `+ z` will allocate the final array.  If you need to squeeze out every bit of performance, you can avoid the intermediate temporary array like this:

```
r = x * y
r += z
```

That will only allocate a single array, which is nearly optimal assuming you don't want to mutate the inputs.  If you do want to mutate them, you could instead do this:

```
x *= y # or np.mul(x, y, out=x)
x += z # or np.add(x, z, out=x)
```

Then you allocate nothing.

The above may still not be optimal if the data do not fit in cache, because you have to traverse `x` twice.  You can solve this problem using Numba, by writing a vectorized function:

```
import numba

@numba.vectorize 
def fma(x, y, z): 
    return x * y + z
```

Now when you run `fma(x, y, z)` it will visit the first element of each array, run `x * y + z` on those three elements, detect the type of the result, allocate an output array of that type, and then do the calculation for the rest of the elements.

Putting it all together, doing a single pass over the inputs and allocating nothing:

```
fma(x, y, z, out=x) # can also use out=y or out=z
```

Comment: I mean with high order function, you can express lots of things e.g,
lambda (x,y,z,d): 2 * x * y + z + d)
this still could be zero allocated without jumping hoops as you mentioned, unclear why this pattern is not exploited

Comment: @bobzhang: It is exploitable, just say `numba.vectorize(lambda x,y,z,d: 2 * x * y + z + d)` and you have exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: numba seems interesting, but it seems not that popular, given this use case is quite common, do you have any idea why numpy does not provide in the first place?

Comment: It's a lot of work to implement, and NumPy doesn't aim to provide absolutely everything everyone could need.